# css inline list margins

Tags: css

I have an inline list that I am trying to get to "fill" the entire width of it's div.

If I use a margin-right on the list the last element will either not reach the end of the div (because it had the right margin) or the right margin will force it to go to the next row as it exceeds the width of the div.

Here is an excample of what I am describing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zphB3.png

my html:

```
<div id="footerstick" style="background:url(site_files/bg_shears.png) repeat-x; ">
    <div id="footer_wrap">
        <div id="footer_top_shelf">
            <ul>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
                <li>FAQ</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Distribution</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

my css:

```
#footerstick {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -230px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 230px;
    clear:both;
    }
#footer_wrap {width:980px; margin:auto;}    
#footer_top_shelf {height:70px; overflow:hidden; }
#footer_top_shelf ul li {display:inline; list-style:none; color:#c7c7c7; font-size:30px; margin-right:85px; line-height:75px; text-transform:uppercase; font-family:myriad pro; }
```

Comment: How can I have the first list element be all the way on the left and the last element be all the way on the right. I don't think i want to use nth child selector either because that isnt compatible with older broswers is it?

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
#footer_top_shelf ul li + li{
  margin-left:85px;
}
```

Comment: What does the plus do? This doesn't seem to work I am just getting the last list element removed entirely.

Comment: '+' symbol is an "Adjacent sibling selector" It has the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

Answer (score 0):

Try below css - after seeing your image and as per your requirement, if i am getting your problem correct the this updated css should help you.

```
#footerstick {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -230px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 230px;
    clear:both;
    }
#footer_wrap {width:980px; margin:auto;}    
#footer_top_shelf {height:70px; overflow:hidden;}

#footer_top_shelf ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer_top_shelf ul li {
display:inline; 
list-style:none; 
color:#c7c7c7; 
font-size:30px; 
margin:0px 40px; 
line-height:75px; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
font-family:myriad pro; 
}
```

Note: Can you show your real time code, so we can identify easily how your code working and where you are facing problem.

Comment: that is sort of ok.. Not exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Because there is now a left margin on the first element moving it away from the left side and a right margin on the last element moving it away from the right side. On the other hand it might be fine maybe what I was thinking isn't even nice looking..